# Why do people use searchable online resumé and how to make the most of it?

Tags: resume, job-search, online-presence

I've read dozens of views and opinions about posting resumé online and have no doubts about that: it should be done. I mean not only and not particularly LinkedIn but rather some special service for building online CV, either in a form of blog or portfolio, or whatever. 
 I would like to raise question from another angle: **how to post it online and take the most advantage of posting?**

- What are the pros and cons of searchable CV?
- Do recruiters really use such direct googling?
- How to make it searchable but not subject to risk/deceit?

I don't care about email and phone spam (contacts are easily replaceable), but my privacy is a great concern for me. I feel uncomfortable when my private details are in public access.

Please, share your experinces how you did it in a secure and efficient way.

Comment: If you are a programmer (or in tech), StackExchange has a careers site dedicated to just this! http://careers.stackoverflow.com/ (It will let you filter who can see it... e.g. if you want to hide it from your current employer)

Comment: I generally go with putting the CV online in an HTML indexable/readable format, but then have a couple of links at the top for a Word Doc and PDF (and LibreOffice, if you want) copy, too. That way anyone finding it can take their pick of reading it on the spot, or downloading it in their preferred format.

Comment: "I don't care about email and phone spam (contacts are easily replaceable), but my privacy is a great concern for me." <-- If your email address is not private, what is? To keep information private online, you really ought not to publish that information (LinkedIn included). For example, to keep your phone number private, you could include a phrase such as "Phone number available upon request." That way, you can at least control who gets access (if they ask you).

Comment: @Brandin, phone number and email are easily changeable, but my private details are not. I mean my previous jobs, age, residence, real name and etc. Conversely I can switch to another email or phone in a few clicks and forget about it.

Comment: @Suncatcher When you publish something online, it becomes public. So if you want to keep your age, residence, etc. private, you've got to be very selective about what you publish. Alternatively you could include a note like "Full resume/details available upon request" and then control who you send your full resume to.

Answer (score 4):

The lesson I learned is to not put your personal number as searchable. The fun fact is once you're in the "system" you're always going to be in the system regardless if your resume still online or not. Take for example 10 years ago when I was searching for a job right out of college I posted on I think it was Monster at that time. I used my parent's home phone, which is the only time I ever did, and to this day they say they still get calls asking if I'm "available" and they're "really impressed" with my resume which clearly they couldn't be.

In recent times, the resume I posted I only ever seen recruiters who claim they like my resume but ask if I want a job in a area far, far away from where I live which is clearly what I consider spam email. The lesson I learned is to never post phone numbers, and only post a email account. Give your full resume with name, address, and number only to a company, never a recruiting firm.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you assume your CV left somewhere in Google cache up to now? How they are reaching you (your parents) after you deleted it?

Comment: A lot of places will bulk import CV's and online CV style systems (ie the recruitment sites) into their own database, then simply match against keywords when new jobs come in.